# How to group rows of the table without using Aggregate functions?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

Sample example:

```
SELECT 
   Equip.name, equip.type, region.regionname, region.equipfk 
FROM 
   Equip 
INNER JOIN 
   region on Equip.equippk = region.equipfk   
GROUP BY 
   Equip.Name, region.equipfk
```

Expected output :

```
name    type       regionname    equipfk 
----------------------------------------
TCT     Steel      detroit       8235
TCT     steel      detroit       8235
GTH     COPPER     michigan      8569
GCT     COPPER     michigan      8569
```

I have a table containing 10 columns. I want to group each row by some ids using group by clause. I dont want to use any of the aggregate functions in select query. Is there is any alternate way to use group by clause and avoid aggregate functions in the select query..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you searching for `DISTINCT`? If not, assuming that there are some columns you want to `GROUP BY`, and some *other* columns in the `SELECT`, how are those *other* column's values to be determined?

Comment: In short no you can't. Now it seems like you're actually looking for `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You need to post some sample data with expected result to help you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using `GROUP BY` in an attempt to *sort* the rows (which it only does  by a coincidental side effect that isn't guaranteed). If that's the case, you need `ORDER BY` instead:

```
SELECT 
   Equip.name, equip.type, region.regionname, region.equipfk 
FROM 
   Equip 
INNER JOIN 
   region on Equip.equippk = region.equipfk   
ORDER BY 
   Equip.Name, region.equipfk
```

Both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT` *may* produce output that appears to be sorted - but this is only a side effect of *how* they've been implemented, and many things (load on the server, server configuration, hot fixes, service packs, major upgrades) may change the order in which rows are returned - **unless** you also have an `ORDER BY` clause.